# Long text in Android TextView pushes out other Objects

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have created a ListView which shows different media files with the possibility to play them.
[image]

Each row consists of a RelativeLayout with two widgets. (The SeekBar and the Rest)
[image]

The upper part of this RelativeLayout is a RelativeLayout too.
It consists of three parts:

- A play button (inside a LinearLayout for padding)
- A TextView for the file name
- A LinearLayout box containing some labels
  [image]

They are put together using the `android:layout_toRightOf` property.

This works quite well, unless the file name is extremely long.
[image]

A long file name causes the right LinearLayout 'Box' to be pushed outside the screen.

In addition the whole (inner) RelativeLayout gets stretched vertically without reason.

I have already tried to set`android:ellipsize="end"` and `android:singleLine="true"`. But that didn't fix it.

Heres the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >

<!-- Top Box -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_topbox" >

    <!--  Play button -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_iconBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="4dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Big Text -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_play_row_iconBox"
        android:text="\??"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Size & Duration & Button-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_play_row_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text=" ?? MB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text=" ??:??" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Seek Bar -->
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_play_row_topbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope someone can help me fix this.

Thanks in advance,

Uriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference as the info layout as the root of your items, referencing it to the parent and the text referencing to the info layout, by this way you will not have this problem, I've modified a little bit your layout just adding an id to the info layout (linearInfo), remmember when you set an id is "@+id/my_item" but when you are referencing to it is "@id/my_item", here is your layout modified, hope it helps you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >

<!-- Top Box -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_topbox" >

    <!--  Play button -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_iconBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:padding="4dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_icon"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Big Text -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fragment_play_row_iconBox"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="\?? Ultra Hyper Mega Giant Text"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <!-- Size & Duration & Button-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" ?? MB" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_play_row_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text=" ??:??" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Seek Bar -->
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_play_row_topbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, it does. But could you explain a little more why? Do I always have to start aligning the rightmost Object to the parent and then align all others to that Object?

What's the rule here?

Also: If I do the alignment as you wrote and then additionally add to the LinearLayout of the play icon: android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_play_row_text" the app crashes.

Is this because android cant decide where to put what because of redundant alignment options?

(The play icon should be left of the text view and the text view should be right of the play icon - which is possible, but redundant)

Comment: How would I do it if I was using a LinearLayout?
(Three horizontal Object in a LinearLayout, the middle Object pushes out the right one)

Because I can't use `android:layout_toLeftOf` in a LinearLayout...

Comment: @Uriel32 Answering the first comment, in a relative layout you have to start with those objects that will not change his size, in this case is the is the infolayout and the button, you have to stick those objects to the parent and the text to those objects. Doing that the text will be obligated to stay where it has to be, by the other way the objects that depends of the text will be moved every time the text change. The redundancy you are talking about is not redundant, as I can see the text is referenced to the infoLayout and the button is referenced to the infoLayout too.

Comment: @Uriel32 About your second comment, in a linear layout you don't have `layout_toLeftOf` because is kind of a list, instead you have the `android:layout_weight` parameter, if you have 3 items you can set this parameter like 20-80-20, those numbers are kind of percents. I encourage you to take a look at the commonsware books, they cover pretty well this under-the-hood behavior and some of them are free. Hope this helps, any other questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much. That clearified a lot of my issues :)

The Android Documentation could be better regarding [Relative Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).
I might look at these books. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad you get clarified and this app be on the Play Store very soon :)